# Excel 365 VBA Run-time Error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error on ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Microsoft 365, in this case Excel, on Windows 10.

The excel is a quote template that imports various fields out of Salesforce (ServiceMax) via Power Query and works well. At the top of the quote sheet there is a button that saves the quote as PDF with a specific file name. This button suddenly triggers Run-time Error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

Line `ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=dateiname, quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True` is marked as causing the error.

```vb
Sub SaveasPDF()
    Dim dateiname As Variant
    dateiname = Sheet2.Range("b1") & Range("AZ3") & "-" & Range("BD3") _
                             & "-" & Range("Z3") & "-" & Sheet7.Range("A19") _
                             & "-" & Sheet7.Range("A21") & "-" _
                             & Sheet7.Range("A22") & ".pdf"
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                                    Filename:=dateiname, _
                                    quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                                    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                                    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                                    OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

Previously the error was seen when a / showed in the file name, this then had to be manually corrected. In this case there are no special characters in the name and the error occurs on various different examples with differing file names.
In the past this error has also occurred when the same file name existed in the same folder. I have deleted all quotes in the folder, yet still get the error.
I have gone back in version history, have used older versions of the file etc. yet get the same error.

There is nothing I can think of that changed as the error suddenly appeared in the middle of the working day after working perfectly well half an hour earlier.

Comment: What does `Debug.Print dateiname` return to the Immediate Window?

Comment: Also, you really need to qualify the worksheet for all of your `Range` calls.